# What is request.GET.get doing?

Tags: django

I am looking at A.Mele Django by Example,chapter1

```
def post_list(request, category=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'page': page,
                                                   'posts': posts})
```

This line that gets page is what I really do not understand.

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

Get method sends user information with the request. But what is get actually doing?
This is blog/post/list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title  %}My blog{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}

  <h1>My Blog</h1>

  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a URL you can send parameters. For example:

```
https://www.example.com/some/path/foo.html?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

The part in boldface contains two parameters: `key1` and `key2`, and the values are `val1` and `val2` respectively.

The `request.GET` decodes these parameters and stores it in a `QueryDict`. This is basically some sort of dictionary (but a key can map to *multiple values*).

We here thus look for a `?page=1` parameter, and obtain this with `request.GET.get('page')`. In case no such parameter is given, `None` is returned.

We can use this for pagination, since a page can for example contain URLs for the next and previous page, where the `?page=` parameter, will be incremented or decremented.

The `base.html` therefore probably contains some logic that generates links with on the second page links to `?page=1` and `?page=3` that thus link to the *same* URL, but with different parameters. Django then decodes these parameters, and paginates the queryset accordingly.

Usually one encodes parameters in the URL in case the URL has *no side-effects* (meaning no significant data in the database changes). The advantage of encoding data in the URL is that if you for example share a URL to a friend, he/she will see the same pagination (and therefore the page will *not* per se display the first blogpost).

This is in contrast to URLs that are for example used to log in or to perform certain effects: then the data is typically encoded in the request headers. As a result you will *not* share sensitive data to a person with which you share the URL, and making the request a second time typically has no effects.